# Is there an e.CloseReason for WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

I'm a big fan of taking control of every possible situation on the computer when it comes to making apps. And now that I'm beginning to use favor WPF over WinForms for some things, I'm also beginning to realize that many really cool things are missing in WPF - and searching for alternatives seems to be a never-ending struggle.

Is there an alternative in WPF to `e.CloseReason` for WinForms?

Comment: Be specific about what close reason you are trying to detect.  Don't say "all of them".

Comment: @HansPassant WindowsShutDown and None are the ones I am more interested in right now. The others I can live without for now (Like the TaskManager one).

Comment: Windows shutdown is reported through Application.SessionEnding.  None requires answering the "all of them" question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The different "reasons" manifest as separate events. The `Closing` and `Closed` events are related to  explicitly closing a window, either programmatically or via Alt+F4 or the close button. The [Application.SessionEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.sessionending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event happens at a shutdown or logoff, and information is exposed by [ReasonSessionEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.reasonsessionending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The exit code from the process can be read from [ApplicationExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.exiteventargs.applicationexitcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the [Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.