# Duplicate Window Close Event using MVVM

Tags: c#, events, mvvm, command, window

I want to use two events when closing a window.

1. User [exit] button
2. [X] button in window title

I made a user exit button.

```
<Button Context="Exit" Command="{Binding OnClickExitCommand}" <BR> CommandParameter={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

I also created an X button event on the window title.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers> <BR>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing"> <BR>
     <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding OnClickExitCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/> <BR>
  </i:EventTrigger> <BR>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

`OnClickExitCommand` is used together, but separated by using an if statement.

```
private void OnClickExitCommand(object e)
{
    if (e is System.Windows.Window window)
    {
        if (System.Windows.MessageBox.Show($"Button Close.", "Close1", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            window.Close();
        }
    }
    else if (e is System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs cancel)
    {
        if (System.Windows.MessageBox.Show($"Window Title Close.", "Close2", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            cancel.Cancel = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cancel.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But here a problem arises.

If `Window.Close()` is triggered when the button is pressed, the Closing Event occurs again and it works twice. (Button Close Show Message -> Window Title Close Show Message)

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: For me command for button and command for event it's separate commands. And must be handled separately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an e.CloseReason for WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210650/is-there-an-e-closereason-for-wpf)

Comment: You could try: e.Handled = true (not sure what prop's name is, might be IsHandled). This should stop this event from further firing

Comment: The same is true even if it is handled separately. I asked about this because the Closed event works after the button Command works. / My program is made of Library module, so application control is difficult.